# Prestashop Find path to product orginal image in .tpl

Tags: prestashop, smarty

In Prestashop 1.7 product .tpl file there is f.e.

```
{$product.default_image.bySize.large_default.url}
```

variable which resolving one of auto-generated thumbnail of name '{id}-large_default.jpg'. Is there a variable which contains orginal uploaded picture of name '{id}.jpg' in the same folder? If it's not is there a way to get path to that image in .tpl file?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do:

`{$product.default_image.bySize.large_default.url|replace:'-large_default':''}`

not an ideal way, but it works :)

Comment: Hey Krystian, I read your blog recently, your interview and about upcoming Prestashop 8, Good Job :) Nice solution thank you :) I was thinking radher about writing a python script and change all generated thumbnails to orginal photo instead (slower loading, but good quality picture everywhere - big difference)

Comment: And in the end I would need a .webp format support, but I don't find out how yet :) Paid modules don't satisfy me, they want to generate somthing (often with errors), but I want to upload a .wepb format not generate :)